# Return opportunity list for accountteammember

Tags: apex

I'm trying to return a list of opportunities that fit the soql criteria but only need opportunities for which the user is part of the AccountTeamMember of the parent Account.
For instance, user A is account team member for multiple accounts. The controller should return a list of opportunities from these accounts only.

Thanks

```
public class OpportuityCustomController {
    public string uId{ get; set;}
    public string SFUrl{ get; set;}
    List<Opportunity> opps;
    public list<Opportunity>getOpportuityCustomController(){
      Map<Id, Id> oppMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
      System.debug('--------uId-----'+uId);
      SFUrl=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
      for(AccountTeamMember atm :[Select a.UserId, a.AccountId From AccountTeamMember a where UserId = :uId]){
        oppMap.put(atm.AccountId,atm.UserId);
      }
      if(!oppMap.isEmpty())
        opps = new List<Opportunity>();
      opps = [SELECT Id, Name, Effective_Date__c, Account.Name, AccountId, StageName 
               FROM Opportunity WHERE Notification_Date__c = TODAY AND 
                    StageName = 'Closed Won' AND 
                    AccountId IN :oppMap.keyset() LIMIT 50000];
      return opps;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Limit 50000` is a bit of a joke here as your VF page won't be able to handle 50,000 Opportunities; VF iteration component can only process 1000 max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the term for this type of query is inner-join sub-select.

```
List<Opportunity> records = [
    SELECT Id FROM Opportunity
    WHERE AccountId IN (
        SELECT AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember
        WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    )
];
system.assertEquals(1, Limits.getQueries(), 'Only one query should be consumed');
```

Comment: `..where userId =:UserInfo(..)  ....`